# discord.js - How do I delete a specific slash command?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

How do I delete a specific guild/global slash command?

I tried searching on google how, but I'm just confused about the command id thingy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ApplicationCommand.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ApplicationCommand?scrollTo=delete).

This will delete a global command by name:

```js
client.application.commands.cache.find(c => c.name === 'cmd_name_here').delete()
//make sure that client is an instance of Client
```

And this will delete a guild command by name:

```js
guild.commands.cache.find(c => c.name === 'cmd_name_here').delete()
//make sure that guild is an instance of Guild
```

This only works on v13 however. On v12 you need to make an [API request](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#updating-and-deleting-a-command)

Comment: dunno why it's not working for me

Comment: its saying `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'delete')` (trying to delete a guild slash command, and yes it is an instance of Guild)

Comment: Then the command doesn’t exist.

Comment: _but it does, mhm_

Comment: What name are you putting? I believe the `/` isn't supposed to be there if it is.

Comment: i already found a way how to delete a slash command, i'll answer my own question later

Comment: This is already a valid way though

Comment: it's not working for me for some reason

Comment: What name are you putting